# android how to make table expand itself as the value gets longer

Tags: android

how to make the textview in the table layout could expand itself, if the value getting longer than the table row?

I've made the look alike table layout(its not table row, but linear layout). And everytime the input get too long the table row somehow will have a weird display, it will looks like it has added margin by itself. the table row moved down a bit.

here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gambar">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@string/skk"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idtenor"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/tenor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape1"
                 />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idAADM"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/AADM"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape1"                            
                />


    </LinearLayout>   

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/thn"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                 />
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/tppb"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/angb"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />

    </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id1thn"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/thn1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                 />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tumbalaa1"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tumbal1"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />

    </LinearLayout>   

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="320dp"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id2thn"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/thn2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                 />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tumbalaa2"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tumbal2"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />

    </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <TextView

                android:id="@+id/id3thn"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/thn3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                 />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tumbalaa3"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tumbal3"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />
    </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <TextView

                android:id="@+id/id4thn"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/thn4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                 />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tumbalaa4"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />
           <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tumbal4"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />

    </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <TextView

                android:id="@+id/id5thn"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/thn5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                 />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tumbalaa5"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tumbal5"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"                            
                />


    </LinearLayout>

    </TableLayout>
```

here is the cell_shape from drawable, its a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                android:shape= "rectangle"  >
        <solid  android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <stroke android:width="1sp"  android:color="#000"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: you mean change all the textviews with edittexts? but wouldn't it will make the value edit-able?

Comment: ops sorry misunderstand your question, i put into answer

Comment: Better use listview instead

Answer (score 1):

Hope its works for you.
Use Two xml file.

1. Table layout
2. Infinite items i.e ListView.

Table Layout -

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/hwDateWiseTableRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Your Listview xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Add this lines in your Mainactivity.

```
adapter = new dateWiseHwAdapter(getApplicationContext(), date,
                        subName, subText);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Bind data in Adapter.

```
package com.example.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class dateWiseHwAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> date;
    private ArrayList<String> subName;
    private ArrayList<String> subText;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public dateWiseHwAdapter(Context _mContext, List<String> date2,
            ArrayList<String> _subDetails, ArrayList<String> _subText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mContext = _mContext;
        this.date = date2;
        this.subName = _subDetails;
        this.subText = _subText;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return date.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return date.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = null;
        try {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hw_adapter, parent, false);
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            TextView txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subName);
            TextView txt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subText);
            txt1.setText(this.date.get(position));
            txt2.setText(this.subName.get(position));
            txt3.setText(this.subText.get(position));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

If code is works for you then correct the answer check mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"   <!-- set width = match_parent -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  <!-- height set wrap_content it will auto append the height -->
        android:orientation="horizontal" <!-- you want ur textview display in horizontal way? -->
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"      >  

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idtenor"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   <!-- set to wrap_content -->
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/tenor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape1"
                 /><TextView
                android:id="@+id/idAADM"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    <!-- set to wrap_content -->
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/AADM"   
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape1"                            
                />


    </LinearLayout>
```

if not can try to set the textview became motion horizontally in a fix width

```
<TextView
               android:id="@+id/idAADM"
               android:layout_width="270dp"
               android:layout_height="50dp"
               android:singleLine="true"
               android:ellipsize="marquee" 
               android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
               android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
               android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
               android:lines="1"
               android:maxLines="1"
               android:paddingTop="3dp"
               android:text="test test test test "
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:textSize="11sp"
               android:textStyle="bold" />
```

in activity.class

```
textview_idAADM = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idAADM);
        textview_idAADM.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: yes i want to display it horizontally. Horizontally expanding itself as the input getting longer and perhaps horizontalscrollview appear when the layout getting out the display range(suppose the max width is 480 and the tables went 600 or so)

Comment: normally android seldom use hardcode height or width, u may use around it api for match_parent & wrap_content, the spacing can use margin or padding to fix, so it able to support multiple android device, i modify the Linearlayout, u try is it work for u?

Comment: nothing change with that weird behavior of my textview. Somehow it moved down. I dont know why

Comment: change the heigh in textview to "wrap_content" as well

Comment: it makes the value(s) swallowed to the right side for example we have 1000000000000 inside the textview it will be displayed 1000000000. Some value hidden behind the other cell

Comment: or if we have string input like "abcdefghijklmn"  it will be displayed just some of them like "abcdefgh", some missing.

Comment: i see, then u need to use the second option "marquee_forever" please look at the example

Comment: no i mean that happen when i use the second option. I think its because the fadingedge, it makes the value fade when displayed

Comment: =.=" cannot understand

Comment: i used your second option(the marquee one) . when i am using it the value fading on the right side its like black to white . example: the value is "9876543210"  , "98765432"  is black coloured text, "1" is gray coloured and "0" gone

Comment: I see, want to confirm the sentence got fading n marquee repeatly?

Comment: did u set following code in ur activity class? this only happen when the textview didnt been focus e.g:-   textview_idAADM = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idAADM);
        textview_idAADM.setSelected(true);

Comment: yes i did like that. try1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tumbal2);
  try1.setSelected(true);

Comment: that weird, tat code is working for me, possible u try with another phone?

Comment: its really cool tho, i can use for other stuff that i want to add

Comment: yup, that is the purpose of this code, for handle the long string in limited width.